# jquery fancybox, get a variable out of the initial function

Tags: jquery, variables, fancybox

This is for you out there who have taken apart fancybox a little bit, or can understand the jquery stuff behind it better than me (shouldn't be hard) :)

Coming from the situation described in [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34827146/jquery-php-magic-how-to-open-the-post-page-from-within-a-homepage-loop-fancybox/34827444), I have added a new value that the fancybox main function retrieves from the link being clicked on.

```
; (function($) {
var tmp, loading, overlay, wrap, outer, content, close, title, perma, nav_left, nav_right,
```

`perma` being my variable; it will be used in the `_start` function to retrieve a value from the `<a>`:

```
perma = selectedOpts.perma || (obj.nodeName ? $(obj).attr('perma') : obj.perma) || '';
```

if at this point I do a quick `alert(perma)` I get confirmation that the variable is being retrieved as expected.

Now, this has happened inside the function `_start`, inside the main function $; BUT, I need to use this variable *outside* of such functions, down in the script within the `$.fancybox.init`, where I will use it as such:

```
$('#permabox').bind("click", function(){
        window.location.replace(perma);
    });
```

however here the `perma` value returns as `undefined`.

How do I get the value I have in the other function to use it into this one???

Comment: just to note, I tried declaring the variable before the main function with `window.perma = 'null';`, but it still returns undefined.

Comment: ...and here's something strange (strange to me, that is). 

If I create a new function to return the value I want, it works like this:

    `perma = selectedOpts.perma || (obj.nodeName ? $(obj).attr('perma') : obj.perma) || '';
   alert(perma); //RETURNS CORRECT VALUE
   _giveMePerma = function () {
    var perma;
    alert(perma); //RETURNS UNDEFINED
   };`

I don't get it though... I declared that variable in the main function, which contains the above. I redeclared in the function "_giveMePerma". Why does it come out undefined??

Answer (score 0):

Once again I figured out the answer to my own question:

1) the variable must be declared at the beginning of the _finish function:

```
_finish = function () {
        var perma; (...)
```

2) strangely enough, var perma should NOT be recalled within the function that returns it:

```
_giveMePerma = function () {
            /*var perma;    this breaks it*/
            return perma;
        };
```

The above will be eventually used in _finish, after having appended the div to the fancybox outer, like this:

```
$('#permabox').bind("click", function(){
        var permalink = _giveMePerma();
        window.location.assign(permalink);
    });//permabox
```

this opens the permalink as retrieved by the function _giveMePerma, which retrieves it from the variables contained in the link and collected by fancybox.

that's all :)